# converting windows based script file to exe file

Tags: vbscript, exe, wsh

I had created WScript file, and I need to make it .EXE file so nobody can access my code,
is there is anyway to do that ? 
I just want to hide my code from other users who may use the script file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think whats you looking for is [here](http://vbsedit.com/).
Conevert your vb script to exe. enjoy:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Script Encoder](http://www.vbs2exe.com/encrypt-vbs.html) which will *encrypt* or obfuscate the script, but there is probably a way to circumvent that.

There is no VBS to EXE conversion that I'm aware of - you could just port it over to VB and compile that. VBS & VB6 are so similar that it should be fairly easy to port the code. Then again, there are decompilers for VB as well. It all comes down to how high you want to make the barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, 
but i had found a useful,easy to implement way, this using the below site, it converts JS and VBS files into .exe files.

http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=ov2e

Thanks,
Manaysah

Comment: This is just my own personal paranoia, but I would not execute a program produced by some website like this outside of a very restricted sandbox environment. On the surface, it may do what you want - but how do you know that it doesn't have a malicious payload?

Comment: yes, I totally agree with you, and this very expected, I extremely Respect your paranoia, 

Thanks for your advice

Comment: I tried the Script Encoder tool that you suggest, its very useful
thanks again